# 3dr quadcopter cannot take off by using Dronekit-Android example code

Tags: dronekit-android

I'm a starter by using Dronekit and Android. When I download the example on Github and run it on my Android phone, it can be connected to my 3dr quadcopter successfully however, it won't take off. I would appreciate if somebody would like to help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have tried the code and its does not even connect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the quadcopter using a different ground control station and try to arm it.  Everything sends the same arming and takeoff commands, so it's probably safe to assume that those GCSs will also fail.  But they should give you a reason for failure. Once you know the reason, you can google the specific error message.